# Getting the distribution of a model accuracy metric using the Posterior of the Model Parameters

Tags: bayesian, classification, model-selection, markov-chain-montecarlo, validation

Say I compute the posterior via MCMC of a classification model's hyper-parameters $\theta$ given my observed data: $\pi(\theta|D)$.

Would it be at all useful to take a look at, for example, the distribution of the Area Under (ROC) Curve as a function of $\theta\sim\pi(\theta|D)$?

I was thinking this could give insight on the generalization of the model if $AUC(\theta)$ is computed on a set different from that used to train the model and get the posterior. Is this correct?

Edit: I was using simulated annealing to optimize the hyper-parameters using python's `hyperopt` library and got the idea to do this via an MCMC method like Metropolis-Hastings which is very similar. The histogram looks nice, but I am wondering if it is meaningful.

Comment: I can understand how this works with simulated annealing but I can't figure out how you can switch to a regular Metropolis-Hastings and gain something out of it. What's your proposal and target distribution?

Comment: The target distribution would be the posterior distribution and the proposal could be something as simple as a uniform distribution across the search grid. So the acceptance ratio would be something like $min\{1,\hat{p}(Data|\theta')/\hat{p}(Data|\theta_t) \}$, if we assume also a uniform prior. $\hat{p}$ is the estimated data likelihood and comes from fitting the model, say through MLE, with a hyper-parameter configuration $\theta$.

Comment: As far as getting a better fit, we may not get much out of it as simulated annealing is more to the point of optimizing your score function. But perhaps computing the posterior would tell us something useful about generalizability. Side note: the MAP when the prior is uniform is the same as the MLE, but again I concede that annealing would help us  attain $\arg\max_\theta \hat{p}(Data|\theta)$ more efficiently.

Comment: That's why I was asking. I would guess that the two approaches will be very similar since SA _is_ essentially Metropolis-Hastings.